# Addition of 2 column values and displaying 3rd Column in SharePoint Online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using SharePoint office 365 modern site, I have to perform some business calculation and display the results in different column and get the sum total for this.

**Scenario 1**:

1. ColumnA with value 42000
2. ColumnB with 70%
3. ColumnC to display results and also get the sum of total column values.

I tried write an formula in ColumnC, SP List Column Formatting as `=([$ColumnA] * [$ColumnB]/100)`.

**Scenario 2**:

If I create an calculated column for this calculation. I am unable to find ColumnC in Totals under List settings.

Need help.

Comment: What is the data type of ColumnC?

Comment: Currency data type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to sum a calculated column for total. Create a new C column as currency data column. You will need to use a Flow or workflow to automatically update value in Column C. Then you can use the built-in total in the list view to get the totals. 
A simple sample here:
[image]

[image]

**Update:**
For choice column, things will become a bit complex. You will need to covert the choice value to a float value. So the formula will be like:

```
mul(div(float(substring(triggerBody()?['X']?['Value'],0,2)),float('100')),triggerBody()?['B'])
```

Change the X to be the name of choice column and B to be the name of the integer column. 
[image]

Comment: I have 2 columns , first X is choice type with values as 10%,20%,30% and second column as integer is 60000. can you help me with formula

Comment: Can you share me this multiplication formula as shown above.

Comment: @Praveen, Sorry for the late reply. If you have a choice column, the formula will be a bit complex. It is mul(div(float(substring(triggerBody()?['X']?['Value'],0,2)),float('100')),triggerBody()?['B'])  X is the choice column while the B is the integer column